# Nginx URL Rewrite with Multiple Parameters

Tags: regex, nginx, seo, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the following URL via Nginx:

```
http://www.domain.com/script.php?title=LONGSTRING&desc=LONGSTRING&file=LONGSTRING&id=THREELETTERS
```

into something like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/script/LONGSTRING/LONGSTRING/LONGSTRING/LONGSTRING/THREELETTERS.html
```

All I have been able to find so far is how to include a single variable. I have five variables to pass through, each terminated by a "/".

Answer (score 6):

you can access a script parameter `name` in nginx through the [$arg_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) variable

rewriting the url with the script parameters to an seo-friendly url then becomes a simple rewrite like so:

```
location /script/script.php {
  rewrite ^ /script/$arg_title/$arg_desc/$arg_file/$arg_id.html last;
}
```

the reverse, rewriting the seo-friendly url to the php script version would be:

```
location /script/ {
  rewrite "^/script/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]{3})$" 
          /script.php?title=$1&desc=$2&file=$3&id=$4 last;
}
```

Basically you have regex captures (each round bracket pair is a capture) that you can then reference with the $1, $2, ... variables

Comment: This looks like the opposite from the question. The from and to patterns are the wrong way round. It's param-based to path based.

Comment: oops, you're right I did it the wrong way around, added the other direction