# Nginx - multiple optional php parameter

Tags: php, regex, nginx

I tried this Nginx rule based on this answer [Nginx URL Rewrite with Multiple Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019570/3581204):

```
location /logs {
  rewrite "^/logs/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]{3})$" 
          /index.php?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3&view=$4 last;
}
```

to make php accept parameters with slashes `http://test.com/logs/index.php?y=%s&m=%s&d=%s&view=%s`, like:

```
http://test.com/logs/2014/
http://test.com/logs/2014/9/
http://test.com/logs/2014/9/13/
http://test.com/logs/2014/9/13/error/
```

and I can't get it to work.

Comment: Try to add numeric part to your regexp: `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: @Phantom nope it doesnt work either. I've tried the simplest rule  `rewrite "^/logs/([a-zA-Z]+)$" /index.php?y=$1 last;`.

Comment: I don't understand, do you want the logs?y=2014&m... to be converted to /logs/2014/... or the other way around?

Comment: @materik `http://test.com/logs/index.php?y=%s&m=%s&d=%s&view=%s` is just an example of what url will be passing to the php to avoid answer assumption